# Can I ssh into an ec2 instance and run commands in that instance using execute shell?

Tags: bash, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am going to launch few ec2 instance with jenkins using aws cli and then I want to ssh into those instance and install some packages in them.Is there anyway I could ssh into these instances and install these packages using execute shell?I can't use SSH plugin as I don't know the ip beforehand.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ssh into those instances and install some packages in them

If this is the only reason that you want to ssh, I will not recommend installing package using ssh after instance creation. better to put these installations in command in user-data or create AMI that has already these packages.

**User Data and Shell Scripts**

> If you are familiar with shell scripting, this is the easiest and most
>   complete way to send instructions to an instance at launch. Adding
>   these tasks at boot time adds to the amount of time it takes to boot
>   the instance. You should allow a few minutes of extra time for the
>   tasks to complete before you test that the user script has finished
>   successfully.

In the example script below, the script creates and configures our web server.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

[AWS-EC2 user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Use this with AWS-cli

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-a4c7edb2 --count 1 \
     --instance-type t2.micro --key-name mynewkey \
     --subnet-id subnet-5630306b --user-data file://ud.txt
```

[aws-ec2-cli-userdata](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/07/aws-ec2-cli-userdata/)

So using the above is the standard way to deal with Ec2 installation and configuration at instance creation time also you will not need instance IP.

Comment: I am using cloudformation to launch the instance.I tried this by adding UserData field in my cloudformation template but it doesn't work

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html